# Why does Github show the username twice?

Tags: github, commit

I pushed / updated a document in github. It shows my username twice (red blocks).

[image: 1]

Comment: no picture indicates you just set the `git config --global user.name` etc, enter github account and linked email for it to show correctly

Answer (score 1):

Each commit has both a committer and an author. The author made the original change, the committer is the one who made the commit. These are *usually* the same, but can be different if the commit was rebased. The original author is also often added as a courtesy when committing someone else's work via a patch file, or an integration tool merging someone else's branch.

You can see this with `git log --pretty=fuller`. Here's an example of a merge done on my behalf by Github.

```
commit d3adb33fd3adb33fd3adb33fd3adb33f (HEAD -> origin/master, master)
Merge: 123abcd abcd123
Author:     Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Feb 28 17:02:22 2020 -0800
Commit:     GitHub <noreply@github.com>
CommitDate: Fri Feb 28 17:02:22 2020 -0800

    Merge pull request #1234 from project/issue/#1233

    Fix: Mistakes were made.
```

In your case you may have made the commit using Git configured with the same name but a different email address; Github will consider these to be different people. This can happen if you work on the same project on different machines and do a rebase.

If that is the case, you can merge those other email addresses into your Github account in your [Github Email Settings](https://github.com/settings/emails).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you already have a `global` git account configured on your device? I guess you have two different git accounts and you're using the one that isn't configured as your global username, to push the code.